# Programmatically insert string width value into sprintf()

Tags: r, string, printf

I am trying to programmatically insert the string width value into a `sprintf()` format.

The desired result is

```
sprintf("%-20s", "hello")
# [1] "hello               "
```

But I want to insert the `20` on the fly, in the same call, so that it can be any number. I have tried

```
sprintf("%%-%ds", 20, "hello")
# [1] "%-20s"
sprintf("%-%ds", 20, "hello")
# Error in sprintf("%-%ds", 20, "hello") : 
#   invalid format '%-%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
sprintf("%-%%ds", 20, "hello")
# Error in sprintf("%-%%ds", 20, "hello") : 
#   invalid format '%-%%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

Is this possible in `sprintf()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, This is possible by using the asterisk `*`.

As mentioned [in the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html),

> A field width or precision (but not both) may be indicated by an asterisk *: in this case an argument specifies the desired number

Hence the code would be

```
> sprintf("%-*s", 20, "hello")
[1] "hello               "
```