# sprintf(): number of decimal places as an argument

Tags: r, formatting

Current solution is

```
dp <- 2
sprintf(paste0("%.", dp, "f"), 0.123)
```

Hoped-for solution has no paste0() and is similar to

```
sprintf("%.{%2$d}f", 0.123, 2L)
```

Except that it works.

Comment: The first parameter to `sprintf`, according to the documentation, is a character vector.  If it doesn't support what you want, then why not just create your own function?

Comment: I am thinking of using a character vector... the example was just the bare minimum but too simple though. ANother example: `sprintf("Cat 1 is %.2f%% heavier than cat 2", 0.123)`

Comment: @Axeman I would argue so, since I am also interested in learning more about sprintf() in general. But definitely the answers there are useful.

Comment: An argument could be made that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536711/programmatically-insert-string-width-value-into-sprintf.

Comment: Yes. Very similar but not identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `*` to insert `dp` into the format.

```
dp <- 2
sprintf("%.*f", dp, 0.123)
# [1] "0.12"
```

From `?sprintf`:

**Details**:

> A field width or precision (but not both) may be indicated by an asterisk `*`: in this case an argument specifies the desired number.

See also **Examples**: "Using asterisk for width or precision"; "Asterisk and argument re-use, 'e' example reiterated"

Comment: My initial thought was what in fresh hell is this trickery, but then I find that it's actually documented in the 4th to last example in `?sprintf`. Nice find.

Answer (score 3):

Some other possibilities:

```
# option 1
prettyNum(0.123, digits = dp)

# option 2
formatC(0.123, digits = dp, format = 'f')
```